# Where is downloaded adobe file stored before its extracted and installed?

Tags: mac

When downloading a trial product from adobe through the creative cloud manager, where is the compressed install file temporarily stored before its extracted and installed?

Answer (score 1):

Check the /Library/Application Support/Adobe and ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe folders. The installers and updaters are downloaded as .dmg files. You might also find them listed in Disk Utility in the Sources pane.